# Is new Hozan spoke thread roller better than old one

Tags: spokes, tools, wheel-building

I have tried to use the old Hozan spoke thread roller (model 700), and have been deeply disappointed. I tried to follow instructions provided but all spokes it produced were either with too shallow thread or bent, or the roller jamed, quite often all of the above.

I see there is new model 702 and I wonder if it is more usable than old one. as far as I can see new one has self centering chuck to hold the spoke, and it has new roller heads which are now specialized for only one spoke gauge.

Comment: Sorry this is too product-rec to be on topic.  Try asking Hozan directly.